# Stacked bar plot for vectors that do not have the same size

Tags: r

I would like to describe my problem / situation first:
I have a huge data set. I filter my data due to a number in one column (>0). In this column there are also 1,2,3. So the plan is to generate a stacked barplot. The bars are indicated by another column (12 different names - see example below) 
This is a small example for my data:

```
dat <- array(c("dbdb1", "dbdb2","dbdb1",
               "dbdb4","dbdb1","dbdb1",
               "dbdb2","dbdb4","dbdb1",
               1,1,1,2,2,3,1,2,1),dim=c(9,2))
```

So now I'm going to separate them by the Number in my data set by `subset(data_set, "column"==1)` or `==2` or `==3` , (thats kinda ugly .. .)

example:

```
mod1=as.vector(data_set, Phospho==1)
mod2=as.vector(data_set, Phospho==2)
    ...
```

After that i used the as.vector function to isolate the column (in the example with the dbdbX entries) as a vector. `as.vector1=as.vector(mod1$dbdbColumn)`
Now i tried to plot my barplot graph by using `barplot(table(as.vector1,as.vector2)`

but due to the fact that they differ in length I cannot use this.

Can you pleace help me? Thanks! I hope my problem is clear , sorry if its not

Best regards and thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear.  Does this give you the result you want?  Note that I've edited your sample data to be a data frame so that the numbers aren't coerced to text...

```
dat <- data.frame(category=c("dbdb1","dbdb2","dbdb1","dbdb4","dbdb1","dbdb1","dbdb2","dbdb4","dbdb1"),value=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,1,2,1))
tab <- table(dat$value,dat$category)
barplot(tab,legend=rownames(tab))
```

Here is the result:

[image: stacked barplot]

Comment: perfect, I tried to use the subset vectors in the table function .. dumb!, thx