# how to get a stacked bar chart for a dummy variable

Tags: r

my column in a dataset look like this:

```
teacher student  
 y        n  
 y        n  
 y        y  
 y        n  
 y        n  
 n        n  
 n        n   
 n        y  
 y        y  
 n        y  
 y        n
```

I used

```
barchart(data$teacher)
```

for a graph for teacher, which shows the frequency of y and n in two separate bars, but now I want to show y and n stacked for both variables, so one bar each variable. I tried many things like `chart.StackedBar` but they all didn't work. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711067/need-to-create-a-stack-bar-chart) help? Or maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12886572/stacked-bar-plot-for-vectors-that-do-not-have-the-same-size)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: based on your comment, is this what you are looking for?

```
library(reshape2)
tmp <- melt(dat, id.vars = NULL)
names(tmp) <- c('Occupation', 'ID')

ggplot(data = tmp, aes(x = Occupation, fill= ID)) + geom_histogram()
```

[image]

ORIGINAL:

I've approached this type of graph using `ggplot`. Here is a simple example:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1618)
dat <- data.frame(teacher = sample(c('y','n'),10,replace=T),
                  student = sample(c('y','n'),10,replace=T))

ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = teacher, fill = student)) + geom_histogram()
```

[image]

You might also consider

```
ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = teacher, fill = student)) + 
geom_histogram(alpha= .5, position = 'identity')
```

Which would look like:

[image]

If you can't tell, the second graph is just "overlaying" the bars rather than stacking them.

I'm not great at `ggplot`, but hopefully this helps a bit.

Comment: thanks. but what I want is teacher and student on x-axis instead of n and y, and y-axis(the two colors) for y and n, so I don't really understand your graph... the stacked bar for teacher should show how many of the data are teachers and how many not

Answer (score 3):

Read the man pages, bro. This is what you want:

```
barplot(matrix(c(table(df$teacher), table(df$student)), ncol=2), 
        col=c('red', 'blue'),  
        names.arg=c('teacher', 'student'), 
        legend.text=c('y', 'n'))
```