# Can I plot two different parameters in same barplot in R?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a data frame Df_agg:

```
    Planned.start.date  Parent.Application.Release  Actual.Hours    Estimated.Effort
1   7/16/14             REL0000801                  0               1
2   8/20/14             REL0000802                  4               11
3   9/17/14             REL0000805                  31              21
4   10/15/14            REL0000808                  102             74
5   11/19/14            REL0000809                  78              80
6   12/17/14            REL0000812                  133             73
7   1/22/15             REL0002534                  12              11
```

I plot a barplot using ggplot

```
ggplot(Df_agg, aes(x=interaction(Planned.start.date,Parent.Application.Release), y=Actual.Hours))+ geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  labs(x="Release", y="Hours")
```

and get this[image]

I do the same thing but to plot Estimated effort this time

```
ggplot(Df_agg, aes(x=interaction(Planned.start.date,Parent.Application.Release), y=Estimated.Effort))+ geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  labs(x="Release", y="Estimated Effort")
```

[image: Same plot with estimated effort]

What I want to do is to merge these two plots into one ,  since the y value of both are numeric  this should be possible by concept .

My ideal Graph would be some thing like this :

[image: graph i want to achive]

PS: I have created the last graph using my messy image editing skills so its purpose is just to get the want I am looking for ,sorry if its not perfect

Comment: Have you tried [Grouped Bar Plots](http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/bar.html) near bottom of the page?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023880/how-to-get-a-stacked-bar-chart-for-a-dummy-variable/ but use position = 'dodge' instead

Comment: I went through the question with mentioned and was able to do it , I should had found the question myself. although the question was not that descriptive maybe thats why I missed it